# Yii2 - Sluggable Behavior

Tags: php, yii2, slug, yii-behaviour

I have configured Sluggable behavior on my model as follows:

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
          [
              'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
              'attribute' => 'title',
              'ensureUnique' => true,
          ]
        ];
    }
```

I need to do:

- If the user fills a form field called "URL", this should be used instead of the automatic generated slug.
- If user changes the title, they will mark a checkbox if they want the slug updated.

I have found that Sluggable Behaviour has an attribute "immutable" but I do not see a method to manipulate it.

Also I do not see a way to stop automatic generation if value is given.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For such unusual requirements you should probably extend `SluggableBehavior` and overwrite [`getValue()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior#getValue()-detail) and [`isNewSlugNeeded()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior#isNewSlugNeeded()-detail) methods to feat your needs.

You may also play with [`$value`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior#$value-detail) property and/or change some behavior settings in [`beforeValidate()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#beforeValidate()-detail) of model:

```
public function beforeValidate() {
    $this->getBahavior('my-behavior-name')->immutable = !$this->changeSlugCheckbox;

    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

But custom behavior is much more clean solution.